# Why is wc -l counting lines incorrectly?

Tags: bash, wc

There is a simple command which prints the number of lines in a file.:

```
wc -l
```

When I use this command to a regular text file. It counts the lines correctly. But when I count the lines in some bash script, this command gives a value one line less than the lines in this script actually.

For example, if I'll run this script with name script.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
    
echo $(wc -l $0)
```

In the terminal I will get the output:

```
2 ./script.sh
```

When use this command for txt-file with 5 lines I see:

```
5 filename.txt
```

Why did wc count so?

Comment: I'll bet the script file doesn't end with a newline. `wc` counts newlines.

Comment: So the last line isn't being counted.

Comment: Try `wc -l script.sh` and you should see the same thing.

Comment: @Barmar yes, when I try wc -l script.sh i see the same thing.

Comment: Make sure you configure your text editor to always add a newline to the last line.

Comment: BTW, using `echo $(somecommand)` is almost always a mistake -- the `echo` and the `$( )` mostly cancel each other (except for the possibility for some parsing weirdness in between). Just use `somecommand` directly.

Comment: @Barmar Wow, that's right. Apparently in my Sublime this is not set up in config. I changed the file via gedit and the script gave the correct result. Thank you

Comment: See https://www.shellhacks.com/sublime-text-add-newline-at-eof-on-save/

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for your comment, I will consider

Comment: If the purpose of the [useless `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) was to normalize spacing, the standard way to do that is to use a redirection; `wc -l <"$0"` (notice also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable))